# Last item in the recyclerview doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a few views on my item layout which is used to display items in a `recyclerView` in Kotlin. Some views are to be shown/hidden based on the conditions. Every item in the recyclerview shows the views (button, editText) correctly except the last item. Even though the last item doesn't meet the criteria to show the views, that is already hidden in the `XML`, it shows those views. I have checked my code but I couldn't make out the reason why it's happening.

Following code is within the `onBindViewHolder` of my `ItemListAdapter.kt` class.

```
    if (model.category == "Food") {
                Log.d("CheckTag", "item is ${model.item_title} and the category is ${model.category}")
                holder.binding.tvDeliveryType.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                holder.binding.tvDeliveryType.text = "Same Day Delivery"

                mFireStore.collection(Constants.CART_ITEMS)
                    .whereEqualTo(Constants.USER_ID, FirestoreClass().getCurrentUserID())
                    .whereEqualTo(Constants.PRODUCT_ID, model.product_id).get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                        if (document.documents.size > 0) {

                            holder.binding.llGoToCart.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        } else {
                            holder.binding.llAddToCart.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        }
                    }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    }

                holder.binding.btnGoToCart.setOnClickListener {
                    context.startActivity(Intent(context, CartListActivity::class.java))
                }

                holder.binding.btnAddToCart.setOnClickListener {

                    if (holder.binding.etQuantity.text.toString().isNotEmpty()) {
                        if (holder.binding.etQuantity.text.toString().toInt() > 0) {

                            holder.binding.spnUom.onItemSelectedListener =
                                object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                                    override fun onItemSelected(
                                        parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                                        view: View?,
                                        position: Int,
                                        id: Long
                                    ) {
                                        uom = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                                    }

                                    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

                                    }
                                }

                            val addToCart = Cart(
                                FirestoreClass().getCurrentUserID(),
                                model.user_id,
                                model.product_id,
                                model.title,
                                model.price,
                                model.image,
                              holder.binding.etQuantity.text.toString(),
                                uom = uom
                            )
                            FirestoreClass().addToCart(context, addToCart)
                            Toast.makeText(
                                context, "Item added to the cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                            holder.binding.llAddToCart.visibility = View.GONE
                            holder.binding.llGoToCart.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                context, "Please enter a valid quantity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                        }

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            context, "Please enter quantity required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                }

            } else {
                holder.binding.tvDeliveryType.visibility = View.GONE
            }
```

Comment: We need to see your code to help

Comment: so where's your code ?

Comment: Question updated with code, please check.

Comment: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As I add more items, I have noticed that it's not the last item on the list but some items randomly don't hide the views. Can somebody help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to the `else` part which was missing in the code.